# Input arguments to CTC loss in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, model, tensorflow2.0, loss-function

I wanted to use CTC loss for a sequence model and decided to use Tensorflow API. But when I tried the ctc_loss function, there were 2 arguments label_length, logit_length I am unaware of.

Can someone please give some details about what those parameters are?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Label_length is a tensor of length = `batch_size`, each of the values will denote the length of your labels.

Logit_length is a tensor of length = `batch_size`, each of the values will denote the length of your inputs.

Comment: How can we create/retrieve those tensors?

Comment: Just make a NumPy array of these values and convert it into tensor using `to_tensor`.